# Derive the gradients of a basic neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, gradient

Given a neural network as following
\begin{align*}
    &J = CE(y,\hat{y})=-\sum_i y_i log(\hat{y}_i)\\
    &\hat{y} = softmax(z_2)\\
    &z_2 = hW_2+b_2\\
    &h = sigmoid(z_1)\\
    &z_1 = xW_1+b_1
\end{align*}
and 
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial z_2}=\hat{y}-y=\delta_1$$
where $W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{D_x \times H}$, $b_1 \in \mathbb{R}^H$, $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{H \times D_y}$ and $b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{D_y}$.
Derive the gradients of $J$ with respect to $h$, $W_2$.

Here's the correct solution:
 \begin{align*}
    &\frac{\partial J}{\partial h}=\delta_1 \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial h}=\delta_1 W_2^T\\
    &\frac{\partial J}{\partial W_2}=\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial W_2} \frac{\partial J}{\partial z_2}=h^T \delta_1
\end{align*}

Q1: I have difficulties to understand the second dervitive with repsect to $W_2$, where $z_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{D_y}$ and $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{H \times D_y}$, the result $\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial W_2}$  to me should have a dimesion $(D_y,H \times D_y)$, $h^T$ doesn't satisfy this dimension.

Q2: why does the second derivative have an order of $h^T \delta_1$ not $\delta_1 h^T$ by following backpropagation such that $\frac{\partial J}{\partial W_2}=\frac{\partial J}{\partial z_2} \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial W_2}=\delta_1 h^T$?

Notes: $z_1$ and $z_2$ are calculated using array broadcasting in numpy, for instance the arithmetic is legit: array(4x3)+array(3)=array(4x3), The principle bechind the scence is that array(3) could be converted to array(4x3) via stacking. [Details of broadcasting.](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) [This is trivia]

Comment: Shouldnt $\partial z_2 / \partial W_2 $ have the dimension of $W_2$?